# How do i make a super tight textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textblock

I'm trying to make a wpf textblock that would tighten in height according to the text it contains.

```
      <Grid>  
        <TextBlock Text="5" FontSize="50" Background="Blue"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
      </Grid>
```

That piece of code creates a `TextBlock` with a lot of space between the '5' and the top and lower borders of the `TextBlock`. I've tried reducing the height, but the '5' seems to get cut off sooner or later.

If you're curious why I need this done, it's because I've trying to do the same on a `RichTextBox`, and then I traced the same behavior on a `TextBlock`, and very few people like the `RichTextBox` anyways. Any suggestions/ideas would be great! Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm dealing with Greek letters to numbers and some symbols (It's a math program). And I'm using Computer Modern as my font choice, So any space not required by the range of my characters are not really required. Here's the range of characters that would be used in the `TextBlock`: [image: Range of characters]

Note that a text like "y" is no longer that close to bottom as suggested in one of the comments :).

I'm also thinking maybe I should edit the Computer Modern font with a software like Font Forge, maybe these spaces are from the font itself...

Comment: There is a lot of space between top and bottom of the 5 because you set Alignment to center.

Comment: Hi, the alignment was set to keep it the `TextBlock` in center of the grid to prove my point. But nice thinking, aligning the text may solve this problem :)

Comment: What you see there is just the height and baseline offset of the chosen font. Try `Text="5Éy"`.

Comment: I made some edits...now "y" is floating again...Don't know about "É" though any ideas?